# Why does TypeScript not allow a generic enum value as default parameter value

Tags: typescript, enums, compiler-errors, typechecking

I cannot figure out why the following code confuses the compiler.

```
enum Enum {
    a,
    b,
    c
}

const func = <T extends Enum>(param: T = Enum.a) => param;
```

Here I constrain `T` to be of type `Enum` and set the default parameter to be the enumerator `Enum.a`. But TypeScript fails at the `(param: T = Enum.a)` part with the message `Type 'Enum.a' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

What am I missing here, for I cannot figure it out on my own and the online resources I can find only cover the basics?

Here is a [playground url](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aenum%20Enum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20func%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Enum%3E(param%3A%20T%20%3D%20Enum.a)%20%3D%3E%20param%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: If a use calls `func<Enum.b>()`, then your default parameter value is not a valid value of type `T`, since `T = Enum.b`.  What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: Similarly, what if a user creates a subclass of `Enum` called 'Something` that has `d`,`e`,`f` values and uses it for `T`? That user would probably not be happy if the default value for their `Something` object was `Enum.a`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error for the same reason as the following is an error:

```
class Bar {
    bar = 123
}
const a = new Bar();
// Error `Bar` is not assignable to `T`
const bar = <T extends Bar>(param: T = a) => param;
```

## Reason

Because `T` might be something that *extends* `Bar` and therefore `Bar` would not be a compatible value.

```
class Baz extends Bar {
    baz = 456;
}
const example:Baz = bar<Baz>(); // will blow up
```